# Symfony Twig - Allowing the use of Twig Globals in a HTML escaped element

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying something rather experimental here, which I hope can be done.

I'm writing an application which has a CMS system built with it. I'm hoping that allowing the user to assign their own twig globals and use them within pages that they create.

For example, the user can create a variable called `foo`. In twig files you would reference this by using `{{ foo }}` since it's loaded into the global scope.

I would like to be able to use these global variables, however rendered within a `|raw` escaped element, such as a pages content.

So, currently to load a HTML element I have to use `{{ page.content|raw }}`. This unfortunately leads to the `foo` variable rendering out `{{ foo }}` as it's not being recognised to use it as a variable.

Is there any way of making `{{ foo }}` render out as the variable rather than literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `template_from_string` twig function:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, yes it does. Does this play nice with being able to render html along with it? Or does it do the same as the `|raw` filter as well as being able to have access to twig variables?

Comment: yes, it should play nice with any html surrounding the include with the function

Answer (score 0):

I would Be extremely careful with this, running any user input through the **|raw** filter could lead to XSS attacks. 
Also you may want to read this about template injection attacks. If you are permitting your users to write twig stuff you may be at risk.

https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Kettle-Server-Side-Template-Injection-RCE-For-The-Modern-Web-App-wp.pdf

As for a solution to your question.

Maybe you could use includes

```
{% include 'AcmeYourBundle:User:PageOutput.html.twig' with {'userVars': UserVars} only %}
```

Where UserVars are the variables form your user. you could then do a

```
{% for var in UserVars %}
```

in the template include.

Comment: Unfortunately since the variables are part of the content itself, this wouldn't work as I would have to somehow separate the variables out of the flow.